# Can administrators seed DBA with more tags?

Tags: feature-request

I asked this question [Does Postgres have a function for converting text into ASCII escaped or HTML escaped text?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/76972/does-postgres-have-a-function-for-converting-text-into-ascii-escaped-or-html-esc) and was looking to add tags such as `conversion`, `escape`, `translate`, `html`, `ascii` and found that they were not available.

Should the admins add some of these tags or related ones? They seem look pretty basic and common on enough.

Some of them will apply if when a database is being converted to a different character set, collation etc.

Comment: I don't see a use. If there's a broader single tag to cover those specific tags, such as [tag:character-set], then that should be used.

Comment: Other than ascii those tags are just too commonly used and serve too many different purposes. Are they really going to help people find questions about converting ASCII->HTML in Postgres better? I don't think so.